# Edited tags showing same tag removal and addition

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, edits, suggested-edits

See revision 7 of this revision history:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18685832/revisions

[image]

It says that the php tag was removed and added, in the same revision.

Would this be because it was removed, then ninja edited (within 5 mins) back in?

Should this display be corrected in this case, to show the php tag as untouched?

Comment: It is just because it got reordered in the tag list.

Comment: Ahh ok, I thought they were ordered based on popularity/number of questions

Comment: They are supposed to be - the diff engine just uses a string comparison here. Could be that the popularity changed between edits...